Return results if count matches record count
I have 2 SQL server tables lets say called child and parent with one parent to many children. I have a field in parent called ChildrenCount and would like a query that will join and returns results only if the number of records in the child table matches ChildrenCount in the parent table. Is this possible in SQL or will this require a stored procedure?

"Is this possible in SQL or will this require a stored procedure?" Stored Procedure use T-SQL anyway, so if you can do it in a Stored Procedure, you can do it with T-SQL. What's wrong with a JOIN and not equals (!=/<>) here?

Please provide a [mre] with sample data, desired results and your attempt.

You could use a join combined with aggregation:
SELECT p.id
FROM parent p
INNER JOIN child c
    ON c.parent_id = p.id
GROUP BY p.id, p.ChildrenCount 
HAVING p.ChildrenCount = COUNT(*);


Yes it possible with aggregation function with group by & having clause.
Select ParentTable.Id
From ParentTable
Inner Join ChlidTable On ParentTable.Id = ChlidTable.PId
Group By ParentTable.Id
Having ParentTable.ChlidRecordCount = Count(*) 

